# SQL - multiple aggregate from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate, derby

Apologise if this has already been asked. Lossely i've these table

```
create table sales (
    sale_date timestamp not null,
    amount double precision
}

create table customers (
    event_date timestamp not null,
    cust_cnt integer
}

create table details (
    detail_date timestamp not null,
    type smallint,
    qnty integer
}
```

Sample data will look something like

```
sale_date   amount
------------------
1/1/2015    1000
1/2/2015     750
1/3/2015     486

event_date  cust_cnt
--------------------
1/1/2015    10
1/2/2015    15
1/3/2015    12

detail_date type qnty
----------------------
1/1/2015    0    20
1/1/2015    1    18
1/2/2015    0    12
1/2/2015    1     9
1/3/2015    0    31
1/3/2015    1    27
```

and i want this output

```
total_sales customer_srvd   total_type0_sold    total_type1_sold
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2236           37                    63                  54
```

I'm guessing, query will look something like

```
select sum(amount) as total_sales, 
sum(cust_cnt) as customer_srvd, 
sum(qnty where type=0) as total_type0_sold, 
sum(qnty where type=1) as total_type1_sold 
from sales, customers, details
where sale_date >= 1/1/2015 and  sale_date <= 1/31/2015
and detail_date = sale_date
and event_date = sale_date
```

Will appreciate if someone can give me working example. At this point i'm trying it in derby. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about derby db.
But in Oracle case, following code works.

```
select
(
    select sum(amount) from sales where sale_date >= to_date('01/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and sale_date <= to_date('01/03/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
) as total_sales,
(
    select sum(cust_cnt) from customers where event_date >= to_date('01/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and event_date <= to_date('01/03/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
) as customer_srvd,
(
    select sum(qnty) from details where type=0 and detail_date >= to_date('01/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and detail_date <= to_date('01/03/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
) as total_type0_sold,
(
    select sum(qnty) from details where type=1 and detail_date >= to_date('01/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and detail_date <= to_date('01/03/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
) as total_type1_sold
from dual;
```

[Run on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2574b/15)

It seems that derby doesn't have dual table.
Please replace "from dual" to "from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1", if run on derby db.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you suggestion. Below seems to also provide what I'm looking for, though I'm not sure if this is, performance wise, any better or worse then what was suggested

```
    select sum(s.amount) as total_sales, sum(c.cust_cnt) as customer_srvd, 
        sum(type0.qnty) as total_type0_sold, sum(type1.qnty) as total_type1_sold
    from sales s
    inner join customers c 
        on date(s.sale_date) = date(c.event_date)
    inner join details type0 
        on date(s.sale_date) = date(type0.detail_date) and type0.type = 0
    inner join details type1 
        on date(s.sale_date) = date(type1.detail_date) and type1.type = 1
    where s.sale_date >= timestamp('2015-01-01 00:00:00') and s.sale_date <= timestamp('2015-01-03 00:00:00')
```

Comment: To learn how to analyze different SQL statements, and which performs better, and why, using Derby, start here: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips